# Executing promises in a sequence

Tags: javascript, promise

An example from this page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p1');
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000, "one");
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p2');
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "two");
});
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p3');
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "three");
});
var p4 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p4');
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "four");
});
var p5 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p5');
    setTimeout(resolve, 4000, "five");
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
}, function(reason) {
    console.log(reason)
});
```

**Output**

```
p1, p2, p3, p4, p5
```

All p1-p5 are executed at once but let's say if I want to sequence it. Once p1 resolves, then p2 should be called, and then p3.

How can I **sequence/chain (instead of parallel)** the promises instead of an iteration through all at once.

It's creating callback hell if I do a manual approach on waiting for each promise. Please advise.

Comment: Use chaining with [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Comment: my attempt, can you please help with the code in an answer, `p1.then(p2).then(p3).then(p4).then(p5).then(function(data){console.log(data)}, function(error){console.log(error)});`

Comment: From the documentation: "The `then()` method **returns** a Promise. It takes two **arguments**: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise." You are passing a Promise instead.

Comment: @str You can pass a promise to `.then()` to add it to the chain.

Comment: @PitaJ You might be able to. However, creating the Promise that way will execute it already. As the question is how to run them sequentially, there is no need to create the Promise before it is actually needed.

Comment: @str can you please help with a complete answer, I'm new to this. appreciate bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, promises *may or may not start executing **immediately** after creation*.
(Note: by immediately, it is relative to the execution loop.)

In your above code, `p1` to `p5` starts counting down as soon as you leave the current execution loop.

To ensure the promises does not get executed before you want them to, you would have to wrap them in a promise generating function.

```
var p1 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log('p1');
        setTimeout(resolve, 5000, "one");
    });
};

var p2 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log('p2');
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "two");
    });
};

var p3 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log('p3');
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "three");
    });
};

var p4 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log('p4');
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "four");
    });
};

var p5 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log('p5');
        setTimeout(resolve, 4000, "five");
    });
};
```

For the above case, if you already know the number of promises you have, you can simply chain the promises together:

```
p1().then(p2).then(p3).then(p4).then(p5).then(function(){
     // Hurray! All done!
     console.log("All done :)");
});
```

However, if you have a variable amount of promises to chain in sequence, you would have to make use of loops (see @PitaJ's answer) or `Array.reduce`.

```
var arrayOfPromiseGeneratingFunctions = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]; // Can be of any size.

// Take the first promise-generating function as chain initializer
var initialFn = arrayOfPromiseGeneratingFunctions.shift();

// Here we're effectively doing promise chaining like the simple solution above
var finalPromise = arrayOfPromiseGeneratingFunctions.reduce(function(previousPromise, fn){
    return previousPromise.then(fn)
}, initialFn());

finalPromise.then(function(){
    // Last promise called
});
```

This solution is suitable for an arbitrary number of sequentially executed promises, so as long as you wrap the promises with a function.

Some other catches about this implementation:
1. In the example we wrap p1 to p5 into a function, so that they don't get executed in any way before you want it to.
2. You can pass results promise results from one to another, by adding the parameter in the promise-generating function. Since the first parameter would effectively be the resolve result of the last promise.

Further reading: https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences

Comment: can we please have some inspiration from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing (Creating a Sequence) and use forEach or reduce with my code?

Comment: The above code already creates a sequence, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I looked up github link, the guys talks about manual, `return foo(initialVal).then(bar).then(baz).then(qui);` can you please add this approach to the answer using my example code.

Comment: I realize that manual approach is the best for my query, wanted to see your line of code for the manual approach and I'd consider it as the selected answer. Upvote for the github link.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise` is executed immediately on creation. You have to use `then` to chain actions.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p1');
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000, "one");
}).then(() => {
    console.log('p2');
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "two");
}).then(() => {
    console.log('p3');
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "three");
}).then(() => {
    console.log('p4');
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "four");
}).then(() => {
    console.log('p5');
    setTimeout(resolve, 4000, "five");
});
```

Comment: Run with your browser debugger console. It is much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function sequential(promiseArr) {
  var p = Promise.resolve(), i = 0, l = promiseArr.length;
  for (; i < l; i += 1) {
    p = p.then(promiseArr[i]);
  }
  return p;
}
```

Edit: Fixed it. Would have failed because `p` wasn't initialized to start.

Comment: not sure why it's not working on my end, can you please put a complete example?

Comment: @user2727195 "not working" is *never* a good description of what happens.

Comment: turns out, it's not the answer, I see p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 in console appeared all at once.

Comment: @user2727195 you can't pass an array of promises, you pass an aray of functions that return promises. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLkzb04z/)

Comment: @PitaJ appreciate bro but can you please use my example code so I can understand better

Comment: @PitaJ thanks, upvoted the answer, also I was reading this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing (Creating a sequence), can you help with the pattern mentioned there?

Comment: i understand your point on passing array of functions instead of promises.

Comment: @PitaJ this is working for me, one more favor to ask, if you can do a for each loop just like http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing (Creating a Sequence), this would help me understand as well

Answer (score 0):

**Let me rephrase your problem.**

*You have a function which return a promise. You need to call this function again and again with different arguments only when the previous promise is resolved.*

Lets imagine following is the function.

```
function getPromise(arg) {                
      return new Promise(function(resolve){
           setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 10000, [arg]);
       }) 
};
```

Here is your argument list

```
var promiseSetup = ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes'];
```

You can have objects which contain functions to be executed too instead of simple demo params here.

Now I'm going to put down the logic which  will execute above promise functions repeatedly with each of the arguments. This will be done in a sequence.

```
function promiseWaterfall(args, promFunc, idx) {

    if (idx >= args.length)
        return;

    console.log('executing ' + args[idx]);                

    promFunc(args[idx]).then(function(){
        promiseWaterfall(args, promFunc, idx + 1)
    });                
}
```

**Explanation**

The above function is recursive. It will call itself with an advanced index value only when the previous promise it obtained is resolved.

Also note that you can execute a function every time a promise is resolved. You can make the "apple" an apple object like this

```
[{arg: "apple", func: executeApple}]
```

Then execute this function where we log the console message.